# "Open this page in ..." dialog

Tags: ios, ios9, url-scheme

We have an app that is meant to be invoked from the Safari via URL Scheme. Since the iOS 9 update we keep getting a "Open this page in *appname*?" dialog. Previous the update, the app would simply open from the Safari without any kind of dialog.

Is there any reason this is happening now and any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a much better experience for the user when they have control over websites opening apps in their phone. Also, this stop adverts (which I've seen in the past) opening the AppStore or other apps without me pressing anything.

Comment: I kinda feel there must be a way to make the transition seamless, since the Install links that appear in a Google search in Safari automatically open the AppStore app without any dialog.

Comment: Universal links, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the alert, you need to avoid print a page (html) between the tap of the user and the store, if you use a link to your servers and then a 302 should work. But if you need to do this from javascript there is no way no avoid the alert opening, Apple did this to prevent those spammy banner that with javascript opens the store. If you still need to use html+javascript before the store redirect there is a way force the app store to open and it's overwriting the location of the page, the alert will appear anyway during the transition. Try something like this

```
window.location = {deep-link};
setTimeout( function() {
    window.location = {dummy-page}; // the faster the better
},10);
```

The bad news my friend about this workaround, is that it works in iphone 6 but not in <=5